# Adding Buttons below TextViews dynamically

Tags: android

I have the following:

```
    Button[] buttons = new Button[forSale.size()];
    TextView[] textViews = new TextView[forSale.size()];

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < forSale.size(); i++) {

        rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.marketView);

        textViews[i] = new TextView(this);
        textViews[i].setText("\n" + forSale.get(i).getTradeGoodType()
                + "\t$"
                + forSale.get(i).getTradeGoodType().getBasePrice() +
                "\n");
        textViews[i].setId(i);
        goodsForSaleText.append(textViews[i].getText());

        buttons[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        buttons[i].setText("BUY");

        // add the rule that places your button below your TextView object
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textViews[i].getId());

        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        rl.addView(buttons[i]);


    }
```

My problem is that my the buttons are being added on top of each other at the top of the screen rather than one after the other below the TextViews.

Basically, it should look like:

TextView

Button

TextView

Button

TextView

Button

I need to dynamically add buttons for each number of TextViews I have (derived from a list). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout..and add orientation vertical to LinearLayout..

Comment: Why not simple use a vertical orientated `LinearLayout` .

Comment: Also, use a vertical linear layout @ParthLotia

Comment: @Gourav yes you are right..

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with vertical orientated instead of RelativeLayout. You will get automatically vertical position of objects